# How to determine the location of a PC running my .net code?

Tags: .net, security, geolocation

Suppose I am writing a program in .net that is must determine, as accurately as possible, the location of the computer running the program.  The program will run in offices all around the world.

Here are a few ideas that I have.

First of all, I have a list of network printers that are installed at each office.  By enumerating the list of configured network printers (which is not too difficult in .net) and comparing them to the list of network printers installed at each office, I can make an educated guess that if a computer is configured to use a printer at my organization's London office, then the computer is likely running at the London office.

Second, I can use IP addresses.  Assuming that my organization has a block of IP addresses in use at each office, it is likely that I can infer the location of the computer based on its IP address, which is accessible through the WMI classes in .net.

However, I have been told that it would be really nice if my program could determine what room the computer is in.  As far as I know, no conventional computer can determine this without special equipment such as GPS or RFID which would be prohibitively expensive.

If I'm not mistaken, some network equipment may possibly be configured to assign IP addresses based on where the computer is connected to the network equipment. (Which port is it connected to?)  The obvious drawback to this method is that it would require co-operation of IT staff at far-away locations.

I'm looking for the most practical way to determine, with as much accuracy as possible, the location of a PC running my .net code.

**Clarification:** Some of the PCs are laptops.  As much as possible, we would like to know where laptops are each time the program runs.  That means that static IPs are not a practical solution.  Simply making a database of information about each PC is not a solution because we are seeking to find out automatically, as much as possible, when a PC is moved from room to room.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755430%28WS.10%29.aspx

Comment: What is the granularity of the accuracy are you aiming at? Room number? Just an office? Location? What would be the differentiating factor between two computers at different locations?

Answer (score 2):

We do it by maintining the list of PC names and the associated rooms/users, as well as assigned IP Addresses in a database.

It's a maintenance headache, but it's the only viable solution to get that level of detail.  And, needless to day, it's only as accurate as the data put in, so keeping it maintained will need to be budgeted for and scheduled for if it's really that important.

Comment: PC names seems the best way to go if you need it the detail. Perhaps if your lucky those names of the systems are structured based on location already. To get the office you could consider looking at the windows domain (if any) the system is joined to, assuming those are different.

Comment: @Avee - Good point.  Good naming guidelines apply to machine names, just as they do variables.

Answer (score 0):

Static Private IP Addresses are configured into the computer instead of waiting for the DHCP to lease one.

If you are going to go the printer way, it is still possible for the computer to move without the program noticing. It is the same as if during installation it asked you for its location.(Which is way easier)

If this is an attempt at DRM, stop. If you want to know the location you could get a GPS, though it will most likely be spoofed if necessary.

Comment: This is not an attempt at DRM.  This is for us to know where computers that belong to my organization are located.

Comment: I think technologies such as Active Directory are usually used for this sort of thing.  But yea, it would be a manual effort to maintain this database somewhere..